# Looping through Laravel validation errors object in Reactjs

Tags: json, laravel, validation

I'm using laravel validation request.
I need to loop the object in the key "errors". 
Im using React, but just want understand how to loop it with JavaScript. This is the json object:

```
{  
   "message": "The given data was invalid.",
   "errors": {  
      "email": [  
         "The email field is required."
      ],
      "name": [  
         "The name field is required."
      ],
      "description" : [  
         "The description field is required."
      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **Object.keys** which returns an array of object properties.

```js
Object.keys(validation.errors).forEach(key => {
  console.log(validation.errors[key])
})
```

Comment: Hi, I need to loop the errors object and get the message. Thanks

Comment: My answer does that exactly.